# Verilog modulo operation

Tags: verilog, vivado

I am trying to design a module in verilog that performs synthesizable modulo operation. I want to replace the % operator in the following algorithm with a synthesizable modulo opeation using generate block. Please help if you can. I have tried to create a block but its throwing errors during simulation in vivado.

```
Error :Module instantiation should be instance name. 
Error2:Static evaluation of top level verilog unit in library work failed.
```

---

```
module modcalc(input  [11:0]dividend,
input [11:0] divisor,
 output reg [11:0] remainder);
 
 
reg [11:0] temp_dividend;
 
 // Create a counter to count the number of iterations
 reg [11:0] counter;
 
 // Generate block to create the modulo operation
 genvar i;
 generate
     for (i = 0; i < 11; i = i + 1) begin : MODULO_LOOP
         always @(*) begin
             if (temp_dividend >= divisor) begin
                 temp_dividend = temp_dividend - divisor;
             end
         end
     end
 endgenerate
 
 // Assign the remainder to the output
 always @(*) begin
     remainder = temp_dividend;
 end
 endmodule
 

module montgomerymult(

        input  [3:0] A, B,  // Operands
        input  [3:0] M,    // Modulus
        input  [5:0] M_inv, // Precomputed value
        input  [4:0] r,
        input [4:0] r_inv,
        output reg[3:0] R ,     // Result
        output [3:0] D
    );
        wire [9:0]  H;
        wire [11:0] T; 
        wire [11:0] Y;
        reg [11:0]   TL;
        wire [11:0]  m;
        wire [3:0] K;
        
        assign T = A * B;
        //assign TL = (T) % (r); // Extract lower bits
        modcalc(.dividend(T), .divisor(r), .remainder(TL));
        assign m = (TL * M_inv) % (r); // Modular multiplication by M'
        
        assign H = T + (m * M);
        assign K =H /r;
        always @* begin
        if (K >= M)
         begin
           R <= K - M;
        end
        else begin
            R <= K;
        end
        end
        
        assign Y = T * r_inv;
        assign D = Y % M;
        
    endmodule
```

Comment: Your block only does a modulo if the dividend is less than than 12 times the divisor.  If you passed in 1000 and 10, you'd get the wrong answer (890).  Are you missing some shifts here?

Answer (score 0):

Your instantiation of `modcalc` module is incorrect.

You have to provide the name (for exmaple `my_modulo`) of the instance as well:

```
modcalc my_modulo(.dividend(T), .divisor(r), .remainder(TL));
```

There might be other issues in your module but the error `Error :Module instantiation...` is caused by the above mention mistake.